# Dictionaries with Alamofire 4.0 and Swfit 3

Tags: json, dictionary, swift3, alamofire, jsonresponse

I'm using this code and at line when I print(jsonResponse["data"]), I receive the return from my API very quickly and easy.

But inside the first loop I have an infinite loop. I need to do this loop because of the return from my API.

Anyone can help me? I'm using the same code to get courses data and fill a tableview and its working... but now for this class its not working for school and I receive the same structure for my API:

SWIFT CODE:

```
func findSchools(){
    let parameters: Parameters = [:]

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "ContentType": "application/json"
    ]

    API.consultAPI(headers: headers, type: .get, parameters: parameters, endpoint: "schools", completionSuccess: { (response) in

        if let responseValue: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
            let jsonResponse = JSON(responseValue)
            print(jsonResponse["data"])
            for (_, data) in jsonResponse["data"]{
                print(data)

                if data["id"] != nil && data["name"] != nil{
                    let school = School(id: data["id"].int!, name: data["name"].string!)
                    self.arraySchools.append(school)
                }

            }
        }
        print(self.arraySchools)

    }, completionFailure: {(response) in
        if let responseValue: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
            let jsonResponse = JSON(responseValue)
            print(jsonResponse)
            AlertView.showAlert(view: self, message: "Error")
        }
    })
}
```

API RETURN:

```
{  
"data":{  

 "0":{  
     "id":793,
     "name":"1",
     "default":false
  },

 "1":{  
     "id":3,
     "name":"2",
     "default":false
  },

  "2":{  
     "id":792,
     "name":"28",
     "default":false
  },
  "3":{  
     "id":5,
     "name":"3",
     "default":false
  },
  "4":{  
     "id":9,
     "name":"6",
     "default":false
  },
  "5":{  
     "id":795,
     "name":"793",
     "default":false
  },
  "6":{  
     "id":11,
     "name":"8",
     "default":false
  },
  "7":{  
     "id":4,
     "name":"aasdasdasd",
     "default":false
  },
  "8":{  
     "id":23,
     "name":"Abbotsleigh",
     "default":true
  },
  "9":{  
     "id":24,
     "name":"Academies Australiasia",
     "default":true
  },
  "10":{  
     "id":785,
     "name":"Acme labs",
     "default":false
  },
  "11":{  
     "id":25,
     "name":"Airds High School",
     "default":true
  },
  "12":{  
     "id":26,
     "name":"Al  Amanah College",
     "default":true
  },
  "13":{  
     "id":27,
     "name":"Albion Park High School",
     "default":true
  }
},

"links":[  

]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add .dictionaryValue in the code and now it is working (without infinite loop):

```
 for (_, data) in jsonResponse["data"].dictionaryValue{
    if data["id"] != nil && data["name"] != nil{
      let school = School(id: data["id"].int!, name: data["name"].string!)
           self.arraySchools.append(school)
    }
 }
```